# React Recompose Causing Typescript Error On Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recompose

I have a very basic stateful component where I'm using recompose to add multiple HOC to my component (in my example I only use one for simplicity). For some reason typescript is giving me an error regarding my props going into my component. How can I get rid of this error?

Here's my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'recompose';

interface IStoreState {
  readonly sessionState: {
    authUser: { email: string; }
  }
}

interface IAccountPageProps { 
  authUser: { email: string } 
}

const AccountPage = ({ authUser }: IAccountPageProps ) =>
    <div>
      <h1>Account: {authUser.email}</h1>
    </div>

const mapStateToProps = (state: IStoreState) => ({
  authUser: state.sessionState.authUser,
});

export default compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(AccountPage);
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
Argument of type '({ authUser }: IAccountPageProps) => Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<{}>'.
  Type '({ authUser }: IAccountPageProps) => Element' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<{}>'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
      Type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' is not assignable to type 'IAccountPageProps'.
        Property 'authUser' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

If I don't use recompose and instead write

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AccountPage)
```

I do not get any errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The typing for compose allows you to specify the type of the resulting component and the type of the component it can be called on, so this will avoid the errors:

```
export default compose<IAccountPageProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(AccountPage);
```

Unfortunately, compose does nothing to ensure the type safety or compatibility of the functions handed to it.

So, for example, this won't generate a typing error even though it is obviously invalid:

```
export default compose<IAccountPageProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps),
  () => 'compose typing allows any function'
)(AccountPage);
```

It is safer to nest the HOC calls:

```
export default 
connect(mapStateToProps)(
  firstHoc(
    secondHoc(
      AccountPage
    )
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, what do you use instead of compose for connection multiple HOCs in Typescript?

Comment: I ended up nesting the HOC calls.  It's not as pretty as a compose-style approach, but the type safety is worth it.

Comment: @JonLamb I updated my response with the answer, an example demonstrating the issue with compose, and the recommended approach

Answer (score 8):

[The current typing of `compose`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/f11a3342486e62b9f62a0fe54263a744bb5a34a0/types/recompose/index.d.ts#L290) is pretty useless.  If you want to use `compose`, you have to specify the `props` type of the original and final components manually, and there is no checking that the types you specified match the list of higher-order components you passed:

```
export default compose<IAccountPageProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(AccountPage);
```

I'd recommend not using `compose` in TypeScript.

Comment: Alright, thanks again Matt. So then the obvious question is, what do you use instead of compose with Typescript? My production export looks like this, where `withAuthorization` is an HOC I use to validate if someone is logged in. `export default compose(withAuthorization(authCondition), connect(mapStateToProps))(AccountPage);`

Comment: @JonLamb Did you find an elegant solution to this HOC chaining?

Comment: @bert The best option I know of is to apply the HOCs in sequence as shown in Brian's answer.

Comment: Thanks dude, makes sense!

Comment: or better -> do not use typescript

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found is to re-assert the type so that you get `connect`'s typings too (including `.WrappedComponent` which can be used for easy testing), else it defaults to an `React.ComponentClass<{}, any>` which is incorrect and gives you no information about the component as per @Matt's example above.

Using your example see:

```
import React, { SFC } from 'react';
import { connect, ConnectedComponentClass } from 'react-redux';

export default compose<IAccountPageProps, {}>(
  connect(mapStateToProps)
)(AccountPage) as ConnectedComponentClass<SFC<IAccountPageProps>, {}>
```

Now the returned component has the correct typing to the connect wrapper as `ConnectedComponentClass<React.StatelessComponent<IAccountPageProps>, {}>` when you go to use the component elsewhere, and now you can also access connectedComponent values such as `.WrappedComponent`.

`ConnectedComponentClass` is react-redux's typing for it's end type of a connected component. In a perfect world this shouldn't be necessary, but it works.

Comment: No, this is not a good solution.  This is just a type assertion to a more accurate type.  The core issue is that the typing for `compose` is unsafe and unless the typing is improved the use of `compose` in TypeScript should be avoided.

Comment: well, avoiding the usage is a solution, but I really think that this is a solution too.
We're all aware of this lack, and, the type assertion fixes it. The exported function has a safe typing, for the sake of the consumer this is just fine. Then, internally, the correct signature is obtained by the assertion (which is a kind of hack). Also consider that `ConnectedComponentClass` sufficiently overlaps that signature (no need for `as unknown`).
This is also scalable, since at the time we'll fix compose definition, you'll only need to remove the assertion.